# Add syntax highlighting to gh-pages

Tags: github, syntax-highlighting, github-pages

Is there an easy way to add syntax highlighting to my various plugin's gh-pages using github's Pygments?

I know that every page runs through the Jekyll engine and provides syntax highlighting ([ref](https://github.com/blog/272-github-pages)). But I don't want to install a blog. I just want syntax highlighting applied to the code blocks in my gh-pages.

I guess I could always just include a different plugin with my gh-pages...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Pages already does pygments, there's nothing to install.  Just use it!

```
---
layout: default
title: Something with codes
---

Happy fun highlighting. 
[More details](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/liquid-extensions)

{% highlight ruby %}
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: Hmm, ok I tried using it to highlight javascript and it didn't work. Do I need to wrap the code in something else like a `pre` tag?

Comment: Do you have the yaml frontmatter?  If not jekyll won't mess with the file.

Comment: Duh, thanks I see now... I didn't realize that was required as well :P

Comment: where do you get the css that actually does the coloring?

Comment: @kentor you need to generate it by your own like this:
`pygmentize -S monokai -f html > css/pygments/monokai.css`

Comment: @kentor We have a nice collection of pygment themes in our [GitHub Dark Stylish repository](https://github.com/StylishThemes/GitHub-Dark/tree/master/themes) if you are interested; [here is a demo showing what they look like](http://stylishthemes.github.io/GitHub-Dark/). I also still have all the converted python files if you need them.

Answer (score 10):

*"[GitHub Pages now only supports Rouge, a pure-Ruby syntax highlighter](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0)"* so you only need to change **'kramdown'** syntax highligher to use **'rouge'** in your **_config.yml** file.

```
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

Comment: then place code between "\```java" and "\```", there is no double quote in fact, and the language code is from https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/List-of-supported-languages-and-lexers

Answer (score 3):

Found this thread as the first hit while trying to figure out syntax highlighting, and I found an even easier way to do it that I thought I'd share. Just put the name of the language you want highlighted after the fenced code blocks ([reference](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown)). No need to generate any css or use yaml.

````
This is regular text

```ruby
# This is highlighted code
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
```
```python
# Here is some in python
def foo():
  print 'foo'
```
````

Comment: This question is about the github gh-pages where you do need yaml and/or _config.yml settings to include pygments.

Comment: I was using github's auto-generator for gh-pages. Didn't realize the question was specific to the manual way. Looks like the generator does make a bunch of css for pygments under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @David Douglas, "GitHub Pages now only supports Rouge, a pure-Ruby syntax highlighter"

You have to put this in you `_config.yml`. This is from the [`_config.yml` of Barry Clark's Jekyll Now](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/blob/master/_config.yml)

```
# Jekyll 3 now only supports Kramdown for Markdown
kramdown:
    # Use GitHub flavored markdown, including triple backtick fenced code blocks
    input: GFM
    # Jekyll 3 and GitHub Pages now only support rouge for syntax highlighting
    syntax_highlighter: rouge
    syntax_highlighter_opts:
        # Use existing pygments syntax highlighting css
        css_class: 'highlight'
```

---

Then for the code highlighting part...

The list of langauge aliases for Rouge are listed here: https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/List-of-supported-languages-and-lexers

It uses all-lowercase latters.

For example, for JavaScript:

````
``` javascript
function test() {
    console.log("test");
}
```
````

Answer (score 3):

The default syntax highlighter is rouge (equivalent to `highlighter: rouge` in your _config.yml file). With rouge, if you write a code block like this in markdown:

```
~~~js
let z = 26;
~~~
```

You can expect to get an HTML block like this:

```
<div class="language-js highlighter-rouge">
 <div class="highlight">
  <pre class="highlight"><code>
   <span class="kd">let</span> <span class="nx">z</span> <span class="o">=</span> <span class="mi">26</span><span class="p">;</span>
  </code></pre>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then all you need is a CSS file (if you're using a GitHub Pages Theme, you will get the CSS automatically). I'm not sure where the CSS is officially supposed to come from, but

- here is a [CSS file for a light background](http://loyc.net/res/css/syntax.css)
- here is a [CSS file for code in a dark rounded rect](http://typescript-react-primer.loyc.net/syntax.css) (the rest of the site may use a light or dark background).

Feel free to customize the css to your liking.

Comment: Do note: I am using a default theme, but my highlighting didn't work. Adding a syntax.css myself resolved the issue. I also had to use the name of the highlighted language in lowercase.