# Add syntax highlighting to auto generated gh-pages

Tags: github, markdown, syntax-highlighting, github-pages, codehighlighter

How to make code snippets highlighted, while taking advantage of Jekyll autogeneration on github pages side?
Is it possible to make it work with *backticks* notation?
Or do I have / should I , move to over notation of code blocks?

---

I have [this very simple](https://github.com/gwpl/tech-notes) site (at [given commit](https://github.com/gwpl/tech-notes/tree/56a6d5b560343319025d03cfb148806084df1f44)) gh-pages branch with `_config.yml`:

```
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

which I added to make newline to be newlines in my code snippets. (apart from this I can get rid of it).

I wanted to make code higlighted, but keep using *backticks notation*, can it? ([Github preview](https://github.com/gwpl/tech-notes/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2015-10-25-auto-android-to-linux-backup-via-sftp.md) highlights it properly, however [generated page](http://tech-notes.grzegorz.wierzowiecki.pl/2015/10/25/auto-android-to-linux-backup-via-sftp) is just black)

P.S. Somehow "[Add syntax highlighting to gh-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6615415/544721)" Q&A does not help as you see under links (or I do sth wrong).

Comment: There is absolutely no CSS defined in your pages. The styles (colors, bold, italic, etc) is defined by CSS. You need to edit your theme to include the appropriate CSS.

Comment: When I checked code of site there is no highlighting... so I am afraid that just CSS will not help. Anyhow I would appreciate links to resources with CSS sheets.

Comment: If you notice, the codeblock (as rendered in the HTML) has a class assigned to it which identifies the language (and was obtained from the fenced code block). That class can be used in conjunction with a JavaScript library to do syntax highlighting right in the browser. Of course, you'll need to include an appropriate JS lib as well as the CSS.

Comment: For example, see [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/).

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615415/add-syntax-highlighting-to-gh-pages#answer-42762258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jekyll [highlight](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting) tag with this [jekyll original pygment highlight css file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jekyll/jekyll/master/site/_sass/_pygments.scss).

```
{% highlight ruby %}
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
{% endhighlight %}
```

[You can also find a lot more css for pygment code highlighting.](https://www.google.fr/search?q=pygment%20css)

Comment: I asked for **backticks** notation ```language . Is it possible? Otherwise is pygments notation better for other resons? (e.g. more widespread? Supported by more other Jekyll deploments etc?)

Comment: My point of view : I prefer highlight because it is css styled. backtick notation needs js to be styled client side.

Comment: I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615415/add-syntax-highlighting-to-gh-pages#answer-42762258